# Subsort array of arrays in python if x[1] == x[1] in neighboring arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I'm working on the mostViewedWriters Quora challenge on CodeSignal.

Given 3 inputs, we need to sort based on which user has the most views on a series of topics.

Here is my algorithm:

```
def mostViewedWriters(topicIds, answerIds, views):
    finallist = []
    for x in enumerate(sorted(list(set(i for j in topicIds for i in j)))):
        returnlist = []
        for x in [q for p, q in enumerate(views) if q[0] in sorted([item for sublist in [z for q, z in enumerate(answerIds) if q in [i for i , y in enumerate(topicIds) if x[1] in y]] for item in sublist])]:
            sbl = [y for p, y in returnlist if p == x[1]]
            if not sbl:
                returnlist.append([x[1], x[2]])
            else:
                for idx, item in enumerate(returnlist):
                    if item[0] == x[1]:
                        added = item[1] + x[2]
                        returnlist[idx] = [x[1], added]
    
    res = sorted(returnlist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    finallist.append(res)
return finallist
```

Unfortunately the above algorithm fails for one condition I found in the challenge text:

> If two users have the same number of views, the user with the smaller user_id should come first.

So for example one of my 2D lists that I am appending to the finallist object looks like this:

```
[[3,3],[2,3],[1,1]]
```

Since the value is tied on the first two lists, I need to swap those two lists. If there were 3 of them as such:

```
[[3,3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,1]]
```

They would need to be re-ordered as such:

```
[[3,3],[2,3],[1,3],[1,1]]
```

The x[1] value is sorted first, but then the x[0] value is sorted next IN REVERSE ORDER, x[0] being a descending sort and x[1] being an ascending sort.

How can I run a sub-sort each time there is a tie on the x[1] value? Is there a way to update the lambda expression on my sorted function at the end of my algorithm that will achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is really dense, complex code. You'll have a hard time finding others who can help you, because it's pretty hard to understand. I would recommend you spend a few minutes extracting out some helper functions with meaningful names, improving your variable names, etc. You have 5 levels of nesting (`if` within a `for` within an `else` within ` for` within a `for`), which is pretty hard to follow

Comment: Yeah, since it's codesignal the code is heavily minified. I really just need a way to sub sort the finalized array - in other words have the matching values get sorted in the reverse order of the non-matching values.

Comment: I don’t know what any of that means. You should heed my advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Since your array has no negative numbers, you can store the user id as negative and then run a descending sort on the list. It would automatically get the user id's in an ascending order.
2. Using `key` parameter, you can use a simple lambda function like

```py
l = [[1,2],[2,3],[2,1]]
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]), reverse=True)
print(l)  #[[2, 1], [2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Looks interesting! I'll give this a try and report back. Thanks very much!

Comment: @EricConklin if this solves your purpose, consider marking it the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Using Abhinav's suggestion with a key parameter in the negative for the x[0] value I played around with this and came up with the following:

```
res = sorted(returnlist, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]), reverse=True)
```

This creates an reverse sort for both the x[0] and x[1] values with the x[1] sort being primary and the -x[1] value being a secondary or sub sort from the first.

Abhinav's code was correct except for it was missing the reverse=True parameter - needing to do a reverse sort primarily and a normal ascending sort as the subsort was the goal and removing the reverse parameter caused this to no longer work.

Comment: You should've added the missing keyword as a comment rather than an answer. Anyways, I've added it to mine.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the missing keyword and also used the sorted method rather than the sort method which was how my code was working as originally intended.

Comment: SO isn't about providing an answer "that fits your code perfectly". It's a general answer that demonstrates how to use sorting functions and also one that helps you in solving your purpose.